# How can I remove this error in XAMPP?

Tags: xampp

```
Problem detected!
19:04:56  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 5768!
19:04:56  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
19:04:56  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
19:04:56  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
19:04:56  [Apache]  Problem detected!
19:04:56  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 5768!
19:04:56  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
19:04:56  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
19:04:56  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Comment: You have another application running on port 80. Shut it down and you'll be able to launch Xampp. Another solution would be to change the xamp port to a free one.

Answer (score 0):

In the apache config file change it to a port that is not used. Go to the line that says Listen 80 and change it to any other such as 1234. Restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

Open apache config file from:

```
installationDirectoryLetter:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

Find line that says:

```
Listen 80
```

And change it to any other port say 2593. Save and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If You Are Running Skype Then Turn it off Or change the skype port . then Restart your xampp.